# JQuery to distinguish one element from a class of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I'm relatively new to jquery, and I'm trying [to attribute a font awesome icon star](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/) (fa-star) to distinguish admins from regular members under the group members bar. I blurred out the usernames, but ideally I want jquery to be able to put the font awesome star icon next to the admin blogs. of the two blogs, only the bottom one (with the blue tumblr icon) is an admin of the blog. 
[photo of the member bar here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Ca0.png).

I attempted to code at first, but I'm a bit lost. I know it can be done, I've seen it on other tumblr themes, and it's through jQuery class and then using css. I'm just trying to figure out how to actually make it work, because so far, it's showing nothing.

(my somewhat) attempt at the jquery script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("title").attr(".admins");
    $(".actualmember").addClass(".admins");
});
</script>
```

the css:

```
<style type="text/css">
.actualmember {
display:block;
margin-top:15px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:bold;
margin-left:50px;

}

.admins {
position:relative;
}

.admins:before {
content: "\f005";
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: inherit;
}
</style>
```

the html:
     {block:GroupMembers}

```
<h2>Mesmbers</h2>

{block:GroupMember}<div class="members">
<img src="{GroupMemberPortraitURL-40}">  
<a class="actualmember" href="{GroupMemberURL}" title="{GroupMemberTitle}">
{GroupMemberName}<i class="fas fa-star" title="admins"></i></a>
</div>

{/block:GroupMember}
</div>
{/block:GroupMembers}
```

Comment: You need to post all your code here. As code, not as pictures. [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: `$("title").attr(".admins");` <--- makes no sense, not sure what you are expecting it to do. My guesss is you want https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I don't know what `<br>` do in this code .. And `.addClass(".admins")` should be the class without dot .. `.addClass("admins")`

Comment: Can you please share an example here or on jsfiddle? Using images of code rather than a starting point of a code example is difficult to help troubleshoot.

Comment: okay I re-edited it so now my code is entirely there. si this enough or do you guys still need jsfiddle?

Comment: $("title").attr(".admins");  -> this does nothing
    $(".actualmember").addClass(".admins");  --> adds class "admins" to all elements that have class "actualmember'. The dot before admins should be removed

You need a way to distinguish between the regular users and admin, and then you can target that. How are they distinguished when you look at the code of the page? Do admins have a different class?

Comment: @the_hobbes that's where I'm really stuck. I don't know how tumblr identifies it in an actual theme. usually you can only go to the blog members page (only viewable by blog members as seen in this screenshot) https://i.imgur.com/pfVxGZp.png . I know it can be done though because I've literally seen thememakers able to do it. I asked one and she told me I just have to .addClass() for the admins and then style it was css.

Comment: Can you provide an example URL that is doing what you are looking for?

Comment: @the_hobbes it's not nearly finished so just focus on the members bar please https://designsbysarah.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0):

I targeted the element using the title attribute and added the class fa-star. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[title='admins']").addClass("fa-star");
});
```

```css
.actualmember {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.admins {
  position: relative;
}

.admins:before {
  content: "\f005";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Mesmbers</h2>

<div class="members">
  <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-IrsYX1O4No0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAKg/UQlwakOCMoA/photo.jpg?sz=64">
  <a class="actualmember" href="{GroupMemberURL}" title="{GroupMemberTitle}">
    <i class="fas"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="members">
  <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-IrsYX1O4No0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAKg/UQlwakOCMoA/photo.jpg?sz=64">
  <a class="actualmember" href="{GroupMemberURL}" title="{GroupMemberTitle}">
    <i class="fas" title="admins"></i></a>
</div>
```